# Error al listar en php con base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli

Este codigo me muestra una sola fila de la base de datos, cuando en mi base de datos tengo 11 filas, a que se dbera esto. gracias de antemano

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // Array temporal para crear una sola categoría
    $tmp = array();
    ?>


    <tr>       
                <td><?php $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];  echo $tmp["id"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php $tmp["estado"] = $row["estado"]; echo $tmp["estado"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php $tmp["lumen"] = $row["lumen"]; echo $tmp["lumen"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php $tmp["fecha"] = $row["fecha_hora"]; echo $tmp["fecha"]; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('blog/edit/'); ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('blog/delete/'); ?>" class="btn btn-danger onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');">Delete</a>
                </td>


    </tr>
    <?php
```

mi codigo completo es esto

```
<?php
//  include_once './conexion.php';
      include 'conexion.php';
    $respuesta = array();
    $respuesta["datos"] = array();  

// Conectarse al servidor y seleccionar base de datos.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysqli_select_db($con,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM lumen";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


?>
<head>
    <title>Listado</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .container{margin-top:100px}
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Estado</td>
                    <td>Valor</td>

                    <td>Fecha y Hora</td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <br>

        <?php    

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        // Array temporal para crear una sola categoría
        $tmp = array();
        ?>


        <tr>       
                    <td><?php $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];  echo $tmp["id"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php $tmp["estado"] = $row["estado"]; echo $tmp["estado"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php $tmp["lumen"] = $row["lumen"]; echo $tmp["lumen"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php $tmp["fecha"] = $row["fecha_hora"]; echo $tmp["fecha"]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('blog/edit/'); ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('blog/delete/'); ?>" class="btn btn-danger onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');">Delete</a>
                    </td>


        </tr>
        <?php 

          array_push($respuesta["datos"], $tmp);
        }
        ?>


    </tbody>
    </table>

    <body>
```

Comment: La verdad, es que no veo nada raro en tu código, puedes hacer un var_dump o print_r del resultado de mysqli_fetch_array($result) en la parte de arriba, a ver si realmente te trae los 11 registros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente, el Manual no dice que `mysqli_fetch_array` cree por defecto un array asociativo, por tanto, conviene indicar ese parámetro: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {`

Luego, no veo qué sentido tiene tu array `$tmp`, no tiene otra función que sobrecargar el código con algo innecesario.

Prueba este modo. También he tratado de escribir un código más claro, sin tanta mezcla de PHP/HTML que hacen el código ilegible.

```
<?php 
    //El código de más arriba puedes dejarlo como lo tienes
    $btnEdit='<a href="'.base_url('blog/edit/').'" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>';
    $btnDelete='<a href="'.base_url('blog/delete/').'" class="btn btn-danger onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');">Delete</a>';

    $strHTML="";   //declaramos aquí la variable de concatenación

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $id=$row["id"];
        $estado=$row["estado"];
        $lumen=$row["lumen"];
        $fecha=$row["fecha_hora"];
        $strHTML.="<tr>";       
                $strHTML.="<td>$id</td>";
                $strHTML.="<td>$estado</td>";
                $strHTML.="<td>$lumen</td>";
                $strHTML.="<td>$fecha</td>";
                $strHTML.="<td>$btnEdit</td>";
                $strHTML.="<td>$btnDelete</td>";
        $strHTML.="</tr>";       
    } //Cerramos el while
echo $strHTML;
```

El código que sigue lo puedes dejar como lo tienes o continuar concatenando tu `$strHTML` para dar uniformidad al estilo en que programas.

Comment: A. Cedano  gracias ya me lista todo, solo me sale este error Notice: Undefined variable: strHTML in C:\xampp\htdocs\iot\listar1.php on line 49                  ---en la linea 49 esta este codigo      $strHTML.="<tr>"; y si le comento, el error sale en la siguiente linea .

Comment: @AyrtonAxel sí, es que mi idea original era concatenar todo con esa variable, pero al ver que tenías más cosas decidí dejar solamente la parte problemática del código. Si declaras la variable antes del `while` te funcionará. Ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: @ A. Cedano gracias eso no mas faltaba.